# HP OfficeJet won't start

Tags: windows-xp, printer

I have a HP OfficeJet 7410 All-in-One.  It had been working fine, however, now it is having some issues.

When I plug the power cord in the LCD screen brings up a loading screen and seems to be loading the software.  Then it restarts, turns black, and the loading screen comes back on.

The loop does not stop.  Keep looping for 5 hours until I just unplugged the printer.

Not really sure where to start with this one.

**[ EDIT ]**

HP Power Cord with brick

- Serial Number: C1458F0XXK02L AC/DC
- Adapter: Input - 120-127V, Output -
  31V

Comment: Does that printer use a special power brick or just a standard power cable? It could be power issues. If not power, I would assume the printer electronics might be failing.

Comment: I'm gonna go with an electronics issue. You could take it apart and try re-seating every connection in sight, but I suspect you are headed for a new printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I worked at Office Depot selling that model (do they still sell them this many years later?) we had problems similar to that all the time. We also had the same problem with similar models (any with the screen). HP basically said that it was a logic failure and we had to swap the whole unit out. Of course, as the retailer we could do that cheaply and everything, so there may be another fix.

You can try a new power brick, as they are known to go bad from time to time. Also, unplug the adapter from both the wall and the printer, let it sit for an hour, and try it again. That can help sometimes, too, if it's a power issue.

Unfortunately, though, I think this may be the end of your printer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought (it's not like it could make things any worse), is there way to upgrade the firmware on the printer? I'd check on that before I dropped more money on another printer.